# WPF Dispatcher thread hangs for hours and then auto recovers

Tags: wpf, multithreading, invoke, dispatcher

I have a very complex WPF UI app - customer reported that UI would hang for hours (~13 to 20hrs) and then auto recovers. I analyzing memory dump as well as debugging the app in VS2015.

My apologies for the long email, but there is no other way to explain the issue o/w.

1. I see many threads while debugging in threading window - would all of these threads live for app's lifetime or some some are transient and will die after a while like objects are garbage collected at a later time? What about the threads with < No Name> and threads with location as < not available>?
   [image]
2. I get data from background and have to do some heavy lifting in UI thread
   I am continuously getting data from bkg thread (1 message/sec) to process the data I call updateDataGrid (msgs received are queued and UI thread waits on updateDataGrid to finish before processing next message).

   ```
   private void updateDataGrid(XElement mainrowelement)
           {
               if (mainrowelement != null)
               { System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate ()
                   {
                      //perform heavy lifting UI work here
                      if(dataGridUpdated)
                      { 
                      //Raise event from one control to another
                       AsyncRaiseOnDataGridUpdated(mainrowelement);
                      }
                   });
                }
            }
   ```

In another class

```
private void OnDataGridUpdated(XElement mainrowelement)
 {
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate ()
        {
          //perform some more UI work here
        });
 }
```

When I look at threads in VS debugger, I see 2 Worker threads at location DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne
[image]

Question:

2(a) Why I see 2 DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne threads?

2(b) Dispatcher is supposed to be a part of MainThread, then why new worker threads are created?

2(c) Are these transient threads?

2(d) Are these blocking each other? - I ask this because while debugging I do not see their existence is blocking the UI in any way, but customer reported blocking issue - memory dump showed stack trace from DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne - but the issue got recovered automatically after 13 hrs - incident has happened 3 times at customer end.

**Full Call Stack for thread ID 11872 from Memory dump:**

> ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+a 
>   KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+e8 
>   kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+b3 
>   clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+62 
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+1e4 
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+7d 
>   clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+165  [[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ]
>   (System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative)]
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,
>   UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,
>   Int64, Boolean, Boolean)+1b 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan,
>   Boolean)+49 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation+DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne()+2f
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(System.TimeSpan)+6b
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.TimeSpan)+aa 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+1f0 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.Delegate)+3e 
>   MyWPFApp.CustomDataGrid.updateDataGrid(System.Xml.Linq.XElement)+eb

**Full Call Stack for thread ID 13952 from Memory dump:**

> ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+a 
>   KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+e8 
>   kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+b3 
>   clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+62 
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+1e4 
>   clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+7d 
>   clr!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+165  [[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ]
>   (System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative)]
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,
>   UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,
>   Int64, Boolean, Boolean)+1b 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan,
>   Boolean)+49 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation+DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne()+2f
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(System.TimeSpan)+6b
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.TimeSpan)+aa 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)+1f0 
>   WindowsBase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.Delegate)+3e 
>   MyWPFApp.CustomControl.OnDataGridUpdated(System.Xml.Linq.XElement)+d6

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Look like a regular deadlocking issue to me, you've probably got some thread causing the deadlock and doing some repetitive task that involves memory allocations that aren't being cleaned up by the GC. After 13+ hours you run out of memory, the problem task crashes out, the deadlock is resolved and the GC cleans everything up. Try periodically logging your available memory to a log file, if you see it creeping up over those 13 hours then your next task is to track down the leak; whichever task is causing it is the one causing your deadlock.

Comment: Thanks @MarkFeldman, do you think that the worker thread stack trace which ends in "System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne" is blocked?